# Jenkins does not recognize HOMESHARE variable and remote call on slave fails

Tags: jenkins

I am not sure, if this is the correct community to ask Jenkins questions - if not please feel free to move the question.

I am trying to add my local machine as a local slave to an existing job. My problem is that I cannot make the job run, as I get a remote call fails exception. As EnvInject tells me that two variables are missing just the line above I though there maybe is a connection there. But when I look into the environment variables the variables are set correctly and I have read and write access there. So what else could be the cause of the failed remote call? The Stacktrace doesn't tell me much:

```
C:\Temp\test_slave>exit 0 
[EnvInject] - Script executed successfully.
[EnvInject] - Injecting contributions.
Building remotely on test_slave (win_test) in workspace C:\Temp\test_slave\workspace\<job>
[EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'HOMESHARE' variable.
[EnvInject] - Unset unresolved 'pkidata' variable.
RTC : checkout...
FATAL: RTC : checkout failure: remote file operation failed: C:\Temp\test_slave\workspace\<job> at hudson.remoting.Channel@1453477:test_slave: java.io.IOException: Remote call on test_slave failed
java.io.IOException: remote file operation failed: C:\Temp\test_slave\workspace\<job> at hudson.remoting.Channel@1453477:test_slave: java.io.IOException: Remote call on test_slave failed
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:986)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCScm.checkout(RTCScm.java:1606)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1269)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Remote call on test_slave failed
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:789)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:979)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/OperationCanceledException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCFacadeFactory.newFacade(RTCFacadeFactory.java:240)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCFacadeFactory.getFacade(RTCFacadeFactory.java:71)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCBuildResultSetupTask.invoke(RTCBuildResultSetupTask.java:120)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCBuildResultSetupTask.invoke(RTCBuildResultSetupTask.java:38)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to test_slave(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCFacadeClassLoader.loadClass(RTCFacadeClassLoader.java:81)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCFacadeFactory.newFacade(RTCFacadeFactory.java:240)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCFacadeFactory.getFacade(RTCFacadeFactory.java:71)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCBuildResultSetupTask.invoke(RTCBuildResultSetupTask.java:120)
    at com.ibm.team.build.internal.hjplugin.RTCBuildResultSetupTask.invoke(RTCBuildResultSetupTask.java:38)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR: RTC : checkout failure: remote file operation failed: C:\Temp\test_slave\workspace\GETRAG\GG-ECMot_AP_0160A_DEV_IFX~SlaveBuild at hudson.remoting.Channel@1453477:test_slave: java.io.IOException: Remote call on test_slave failed
Performing Post build task...
Could not match :Code generation phase  : False
Logical operation result is FALSE
```

Additional information:

The variable EnvInject says are missing are set like the following:

```
HOMESHARE    \\<server>\<user>$
[...]
pkidata    \\<server>\<user>$
```

From the Slave side everything seems to be connected just fine. This is the commandline read-out.

```
Nov 23, 2016 10:49:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://<address>.com:8080/]
Nov 23, 2016 10:49:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Nov 23, 2016 10:49:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to <address>.com:49599
Nov 23, 2016 10:49:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
Nov 23, 2016 10:49:29 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
```

Comment: how is the slave connected to the master?

Comment: The slave is connected via Java Web Start. I executed the corresponding command in a command line on my machine.